# Magento 2 How to extend rules.js to add custom validation rules?

Tags: magento2, validation

How to extend rules.js to add custom validation rules?

Comment: is this working for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to set `rules.js` inside your theme.

First create folder inside your theme Magento_Ui if its already exist then skip it.

keep file into below location from core module.

```
app/code/Package/themename/Magento_Ui/web/js/lib/validation/rules.js
```

**Remove var folder.
Remove pub/static folder contents and run deploy command,**

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: it works by adding to app/code/Package/themename/Magento_Ui/web/js/lib/validation/rules.js instead of app/code/Package/themename/Magento_Ui/view/frontend/web/js/lib/validation/rules.js

Comment: yes, i have mentioned view/frontend its not working for theme. I have updated my answer. thanks.

Comment: Hi Rakesh, I have fallow above step but it did not work for me. can you help me.

Comment: Shall i define this rules.js(overrided js), in checkout layout file

Answer (score 4):

This is the **best way** to add a new rule **without override the file rules.js** and use on LayoutProcessor.php or jsLayout.

```
define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/validator'
    ],function ($,validator) {
    "use strict";
    return validator.addRule('validade-name-of-validation',
        function (value) {
            return /* your function */
        }, $.mage.__('Your error message.')
    );
});
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

They way that worked for me was by extending Magento Validation:

1) Change your theme in `app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/requirejs-config.js`, adding:

```
var config = {
map: {
    '*': {
        myCustomValidation: 'js/validation'
    }
}};
```

2) Then, create the file validation.js in `app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/web/js/` with the content:

```
requirejs([
'jquery',
'Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/utils',
'jquery/ui',
'jquery/validate',
'mage/translate'
], function($, utils){
'use strict';
$.validator.addMethod(
    "validate-zip-au",
    function (value) {
        return utils.isEmptyNoTrim(value) || /(^\d{4}$)/.test(value);

    },
    $.mage.__('Please enter a valid postcode (Ex: 9060).')
);
});
```

Please note **"validate-zip-au"** is the name of my custom rule. Please replace it with whatever name you want.

3) Now add the class to the field you want in your phtml file. In my case, the class is **"validate-zip-au"**

4) At the end of your phtml add initialise it:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
        "myCustomValidation": {}
    }
}
```

Redeploy your assets `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` and flush your cache.

Answer (score 0):

```
app/code/Package/themename
```

What does it mean Package in this case ? In example I have created custom theme, my path is:

```
app/design/frontend/vagwan/moto
```

What should I write in "Package" and what in "themename" ? Is my path would be like:

```
app/code/vagwan/moto/Magento_Ui/web/js/lib/validation/rules.js
```

Am I correct ?