# How to extend rules.js in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, javascript, rules

I try to **overwrite rules.js** from `vendor/Magento_Ui/web/js/lib/validation/rules.js` in my custom theme but it dosen't work.
I found this solution but it's not working for me : [Magento 2 How to extend rules.js to add custom validation rules?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125850/magento-2-how-to-extend-rules-js-to-add-custom-validation-rules)

Does anyone have any idea if it's other method to **overwrite rule.js file**?

Comment: Did you remove static content and deploy again?

Comment: yes. so the step should be: create a empty Magento_Ui folder in my custom theme,  in design/frontendand/Package/themename and then in app/code/Package/themename/Magento_Ui/web/js/lib/validation/rules.js?

Comment: can i use any package name?  i mean sould i put my file in any module and then create there a themename folder?

Comment: Did you clear Magento cache and Browser cache?

Comment: yes. but the step i follow it's correct?

Comment: Have you remove browser cache?

Comment: php bin/magento cache:clean  and php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: i have a  chrome extensions for remove cash in browser

Comment: but for me it;s not so clear if i need to create an emtpy folder in my app/design/frontend/Package/themename/ with name Magento_Ui and then in app/code to put my js file

Comment: @AlinLupoiu you need to create a custom theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you **need to create a custom theme**. You should read more here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

Put the validation rule in your custom theme with following path:

```
app/design/frontend/Package/themename/Magento_Ui/web/js/lib/validation/rules.js
```

[image]

Comment: i already have a custom theme and i overwrite a lot of phtml files

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: no working.  you said app/design and http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125850/magento-2-how-to-extend-rules-js-to-add-custom-validation-rules said app/code

Comment: This answer which you gave may be wrong path! I'm pretty sure that my answer above can work.

Comment: this is work for you?

Comment: because the rules.js is  in in base file not in the frontend file in vendor/Module_Ui

Comment: `vendor/Magento_Ui/web/js/lib/validation/rules.js`? It should be: `vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/lib/validation/rules.js`? You're wrong path?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51432/discussion-between-khoa-truongdinh-and-alin-lupoiu).

Comment: How we can add custom error message in magento 2 for registration form? where and which file?